# Can't Connect My Node.js To My MongoDB Locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I tried connecting my app.js file to my local mongoDB shell
after installing the npm mongodb dependency.

This is what i'm getting

```
$ node app.js
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Dahmie Nahty\Desktop\NativeDriverProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:293:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to connect?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Your_collection_name');
```

To connect to the db.

Try:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/Your_collection_name');
```

Instead of that, it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer, it worked out partially, later had to add my port to it before it works  Const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db-Name'

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your Node.js application is unable to establish a connection to a MongoDB server running on the localhost at port 21017. This error typically occurs when MongoDB is not running or not accessible at the specified address and port.
I also got this error. Its very easy to resove this error:

1.Just reinstall MongoDB.

2. Set path in enviroment variable (in System variables):
   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin
3. Reinstall Mongodb shell at : C:\Program Files\MongoDB
4. Set this path to env. variables : C:\Program Files\MongoDB